# nhibernate group by and join query

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

I need nhiberante query (not HQL) equivalent following SQL:

```
SELECT ur.*
FROM (SELECT MAX(requestTime) rt, macAddress ma
    FROM UpdateRequests
    GROUP BY macAddress) mur
JOIN dbo.UpdateRequests ur
ON mur.ma = ur.macAddress AND mur.rt = ur.requestTime
```

I had no luck with other similar examples on stackoverflow.
Having UpdateRequest mapping, it seems that is not possible with Query API, how about QueryOver?

Comment: You can't query from derived tables with QueryOver so this *exact* query isn't possible. However I think this could be rewritten with a subquery, is that an acceptable workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally one Guru suggested me to change SQL query without changing execution plan:

```
SELECT  ur.*
FROM    [dbo].[UpdateRequests] AS ur
WHERE   ur.[RequestTime] = (SELECT MAX(mur.[RequestTime])
                            FROM   [dbo].[UpdateRequests] mur
                            WHERE  mur.[MacAddress] = ur.[MacAddress])
```

So in code it transforms into:

```
session
    .Query<UpdateRequest>()
    .Where(ur => ur.RequestTime == session.Query<UpdateRequest>()
                                          .Where(mur => mur.MacAddress == ur.MacAddress)
                                          .Max(mur => mur.RequestTime))
    .ToList();
```

And this is exactly what i need.